# Android cant access play store after installing app from outside the play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have a rooted android phone where i install an app from outside the play store. and now I cant access play store anymore. I search for solution and found this. But I can't even edit the host file. I use ES file explorer to edit. This are in the host file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.124.218.80
android.clients.google.com
mtalk.google.com
```

My questions is

How to edit the host file?
What can I delete from the host file?(what are the extra lines apart from default in the host file?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people vote down my question. Anyway I ask the same question on another comunity and got the solution. I'am posting the answer for anyone who has the same problem.

[Original Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125518/android-cant-access-play-store-after-installing-app-from-outside-the-play-store)

Steps:

1. Go to **ES file explorer** click menu on the right.
2. Scroll down to **Root Explorer** and turn it on, then click again on the Root Explorer it will open up a new menu.
3. Click `mount R/W` it will open a new menu.
4. Turn on the `RW` option on for the `/system`.
5. Go to the host file `/system/etc/hosts` and edit the file, then saved.